# How to Decrypt the encrypted string using CryptoJS (SHA512)

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am using CrypstoJS ( from https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js ) for the encryption and decryption.

I encrypted a string as shown below:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
```

Then how to decrypt it??? 
I want to use SHA512 for encryption/decryption.

Please help me..

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

> Keyed-hash message authentication codes (HMAC) is a mechanism for message authentication using cryptographic hash functions.

You can't decrypt it. It is hashed, not encrypted.

---

If you want to decrypt your data, then use a [cipher function](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Ciphers) instead of a hash function.

---

That said, most of the time, when people want to do encryption/decryption with JavaScript, they should be using SSL instead.